# "Role" or "Roles"

Tags: word-choice

Though I am a native English speaker, I am having trouble deciding between "role" and "roles" in the phrase below.

> The roles of the two parties involved in a legal proceeding, peculiar to the adversarial system of trial, can help circumscribe whether or not a trial proceeds in a fair and unbiased fashion.

*or*

> The role of the two parties involved in a legal proceeding, peculiar to the adversarial system of trial, can help circumscribe whether or not a trial proceeds in a fair and unbiased fashion.

I would appreciate it if you could let me know which one is correct.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ummm... I only see *roles* in there... but I think your question revolves around whether or not the parties are performing the same role, or different ones. Oh, and consider *adversarial* as the adjectival form vs *adversary* as a noun.

Comment: After repeating both sentences in my head a dozen times, I feel like **The roles of the two parties** sounds better than **The role of the two parties**, for an obscure reason. I might have heard the first one more often than the second one. Even if both have the same role, I would say/write **The roles**.

Comment: Thank you! I meant for one of those sentences to contain the word 'role' and for 'adversary' to be 'adversarial'. I appreciate your assistance! I will go with 'roles'.

Comment: I see only "role" in there. One of them should be "roles", right?

Comment: They were two *roles* before that, now they are two *role*. OP is having a bit of a problem :D.

Comment: I'm tired! Haha. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one is correct grammatically.

Which one is correct logically depends on whether the two parties have the same role or two (or more) different (or the same) roles.

That might sound confusing, but what I mean is this:

- List the role(s) of `Party One`.
- List the role(s) of `Party Two`.

Is there just one role listed under both? In other words, both have the same single role? Then use **role**.

Are there multiple roles listed under each? Or is there one role under each, but those two roles are different? Then use **roles**.

- If `Party One` has `Role ABC`, `Party Two` also has `Role ABC`, and neither has any other roles, then use **role**.
- If `Party One` has `Role ABC`, and `Party Two` has `Role XYZ`, then use **roles**.
- If `Party One` has `Role ABC` and `Role XYZ`, and `Party Two` has `Role ABC` and `Role XYZ`, then use **roles**.

Your sentence alone leaves it ambiguous, so either one might be correct.